# angular material, how to use dark() function when define theme colors?

Tags: angular-material

When I read the demo at https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.input

```
app.config( function($mdThemingProvider){
// Configure a dark theme with primary foreground yellow
$mdThemingProvider.theme('docs-dark', 'default')
    .primaryPalette('yellow')
    .dark();   });
```

What's the meaning of .dark()?
What if I want to make the background color to blue, red or sth else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, it swaps the palette to use dark values.  I am basing this on code in theming.js from the 0.10 release.

First, setting dark() on a theme changes the background values:

```
var DARK_FOREGROUND = {
  name: 'dark',
  '1': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.87)',
  '2': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.54)',
  '3': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.26)',
  '4': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.12)'
};
```

This makes the most noticeable change by changing the background.  You also get this shadow around some text elements:

```
var DARK_SHADOW = '1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), -1px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)';
```

Default hues for 'primary', 'accent', 'warn', and 'background' are also changed if not specified in the theme definition.  This will cause the application to look slightly differently if you do not explicitly set values in the theme definition.  Light themes have a value of

```
var LIGHT_DEFAULT_HUES = {
  'accent': {
    'default': 'A200',
    'hue-1': 'A100',
    'hue-2': 'A400',
    'hue-3': 'A700'
  },
  'background': {
    'default': '50',
    'hue-1': 'A100',
    'hue-2': '100',
    'hue-3': '300'
  }
};
```

And dark themes have a value of:

```
var DARK_DEFAULT_HUES = {
  'background': {
    'default': 'A400',
    'hue-1': '800',
    'hue-2': '900',
    'hue-3': 'A200'
  }
};
```

If theme has no definition for 'primary', 'accent', 'warn', or 'background' the default for those entries will be:

```
var defaultDefaultHues = {
  'default': '500',
  'hue-1': '300',
  'hue-2': '800',
  'hue-3': 'A100'
};
```

If you are creating a custom palette, you can also specify contrast colours by setting:

```
'contrastDefaultColor': 'dark'
```

and defining some contrasting colours with `'contrastLightColors'` and `'contrastStrongLightColors'`.

I personally haven't really been able to make a *good* looking dark theme, and have also found the documentation a little bit lacking regarding dark themes.  Another thing you could do is check out the [palette definitions](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/core/services/theming/theme.palette.js) to help understand the mapping for contrasting colours.

Comment: Hi @laughingpine, it is not yet very clear for me though, what does remain unchanged after applying dark(). What I understand is that some values are replaced (like adding shadows, some backgrounds, etc), but doing so looks like you are changing the theme entirely. Can you please help me clarifying this also? Maybe a short intro about what components is a theme made of will help.

Comment: Apologies if I miss something here.  Check out the setDark (same as .dark()): https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/core/services/theming/theming.js#L494.  To quickly summarize: apart from the regular dark changes, the default hues are changed for md-backgrounds, and the default md-accent colours will be different.  Backgrounds go from 50, A100, 100, 300 to A400, 800, 900, A200 and accents go from A200, A100, A400, A700 to 500, 300, 800, A100.  Also note that those changes are only applied if you do not specify your own values in your theme definition!

Comment: So, more concise, .dark() should use/enable the darker pallet of colors instead of the brighten ones :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it darkens the background itself, not necessarily the highlight colors. Have you tried just applying it and seeing what happens?
Separately, are the other highlight colors appearing as you intend, or is this just the demo code?

If other theming isn't working, make sure you inserted the correct dependencies in the configuration for your app.  You have to have

```
ngMaterial
```